# Laravel 5.1 specifing current page for pagination

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.1

Been working on this for far too long with no results. I have tried.

```
`\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::setCurrentPage($current_page);`
```

returns
`Call to protected method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::setCurrentPage()`

`\Paginator::setCurrentPage($current_page);`

returns `Call to protected method Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::setCurrentPage()`

`\DB::getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($current_page);`

returns `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'getPaginator'`

`$tmp = new Post( ); $tmp->getConnection()->setCurrentPage($current_page);`

returns `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'getPaginator'`

How can I specify the page? I need to specify it manually.

I had hoped it to be as easy as `$model->find( )->paginate($per_page, $page)`

Comment: I am also having this issue, i'll let you know if I work it out

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Suppose you have `$users` to paginate in your `UserController`, you might do:

```
public function index()
{
    $currentPage = 3; // You can set this to any page you want to paginate to

    // Make sure that you call the static method currentPageResolver()
    // before querying users
    Paginator::currentPageResolver(function () use ($currentPage) {
        return $currentPage;
    });

    $users = \App\User::paginate(5);

    return view('user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

I believe this applies to Laravel 5.0 and above. Have to check on that.

Comment: I had to run it with `\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver` else it searched for the class in the current name space. With `\Paginator' it told me the class was not found. This way it works!

Comment: Shane, you could have `imported` the class at the top of your controller:
    `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Your code should be added an if condition to check if user is going to other page, or it will stuck on a same page.

Comment: While this may work, Ive downvoted because this goes way around simply passing the parameter that already exists in the method signature.

Comment: Is there a method which determine how to create pagination links? There must be something what take current request and append page param to there. But I would like to change this proces by route name.

Answer (score 85):

The [Builder](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/5.1/Eloquent/Builder.php#L339) Class has:

```
public function paginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'], $pageName = 'page', $page = null)
```

You can call

```
Model::find(...)->paginate($per_page, ['*'], 'page', $page);
```

Comment: Yes, this approach is better. Thank you @PATROMO.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you @Patromo.

Comment: Works just fine. Link to docs for the `paginate()` function: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_paginate

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

After 7 years) in Laravel 8 I wanted to show the last page if the page from the parameter is bigger than the total pages the after search result. Below is my solution.

```
$paginator = $properties->paginate($items_per_page);

if ($paginator->currentPage() > 1 && $paginator->isEmpty()) {
    $paginator = $properties->paginate($items_per_page, ['*'], 'page', $paginator->lastPage());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for those people who using api and they want to specify the current page in api, they can use extra parameter like this:

`getProducts?page=3`

Comment: It really depends on how your routes are structured and how you are using the framework. The paginator uses "first_page_url": "/?page=1" as default but if you are not using this structure then it won't work.